# Disable a column with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable a column on my table with JS, using a button.

I looked on the internet for a solution but didn't find one.
Is it because my table is created by JS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Bootstrap Table - Filter control</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-table.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
      <script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
      <script src='js/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
      <script src='js/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
      <script src='js/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
      <script src='js/tableExport.js'></script>
      <script src='js/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script>
      <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <h1>Bootstrap Table</h1>
         <p> Mémo pour les options du Bootstrap Table : <a href="http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/">Bootstrap Table Documentation</a></p>
         <p>Eléments de Bootstrap Table utilisés : <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3178/">Data Checkbox</a>, pour cocher les éléments à sélectionner, <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/filter-control.html">extension Filter control</a>, pour les filtres via les colonnes, <a href="https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin">extension Data export</a> pour exporter</p>
         <div id="toolbar">
            <select class="form-control">
               <option value="">Export Basic</option>
               <option value="all">Export All</option>
               <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
            </select>

         </div>
         <table id="table" class="table"
            data-toggle="table"
            data-search="true"
            data-filter-control="true" 
            data-show-export="true"
            data-click-to-select="true"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th id="column-a" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">1</th>
                  <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                  <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
                  <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
                  <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
                  <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
               <div id="tabs1" class="tabs">

                  </div>
            </tbody>
         </table>

      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="js/tableaujs.js"></script>

      <button type="button" data-column="#column-a" id="bouton">Hide/show 1st</button>
      <script>

      $(document).on("click", "[data-column]", function () {

         var button = $(this),
            header = $(button.data("column")),
            table = header.closest("table"),
            index = header.index() + 1,

            selector = "tbody div tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")",
            column = table.find(selector).add(header);

            alert(button.data("column") + " index" + index);
            // selector = "tbody div tr td:nth-child(1)";
            // column = table.find(selector).add(header);
         column.toggleClass("hidden");
       });
       </script>


   </body>
</html>


var utilisateur = [                                       // donnée du tableau
  {
    id: 1,
    checked: false,
    prenom: "Dolores",
    date: "Fermière",
    examen: "host",
    note: "ww.dolores@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checked: true,
    prenom: "Bernard",
    date: "Robopsycologue",
    examen: "abdel",
    note: "ww.bernard@gmail.com"
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");                   // créer le tableau
  var atr2 = document.createAttribute("id");
  atr2.value = utilisateur[i].id;
  row.setAttributeNode(atr2);

  var cell0 = document.createElement("td");
  // var atr1 = document.createAttribute("id");
  // atr1.value = utilisateur[i].id;
  // cell0.setAttributeNode(atr1);

  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");                 // créer l'élément

  var atr = document.createAttribute("class");              // créer l'attribut
  atr.value = "bs-checkbox";
  cell1.setAttributeNode(atr);
  var para = document.createElement("input");
  var para1 = document.createAttribute("data-index");
  var para2 = document.createAttribute("name");
  var para3 = document.createAttribute("type");
  para1.value = "0";
  para2.value = "btSelectItem";
  para3.value = "checkbox";
  para.setAttributeNode(para1);
  para.setAttributeNode(para2);
  para.setAttributeNode(para3)
  cell1.appendChild(para);



  // var cell1 = '<td class="bs-checkbox"></td>'
  //alert(cell1).innerText;
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");                 // créer l'élément
  var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell6 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell7 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell8 = document.createElement("td");
  cell0.innerText = utilisateur[i].id;
  cell1.innerText = utilisateur[i].checked
  cell2.innerText = utilisateur[i].prenom;   
  cell3.innerText = utilisateur[i].date;
  cell4.innerText = utilisateur[i].examen;
  cell5.innerText = utilisateur[i].note;
  row.appendChild(cell0);                                    // afficher dans le tableau la cellule 
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  row.appendChild(cell4);
  row.appendChild(cell5);
  // row.appendChild(cell6);
  // row.appendChild(cell7);
  // row.appendChild(cell8);

  // document.getElementsById("tbody")[0].appendChild(row);

  // var elem = document.getElementsById("tabs1");
  // var mychild = document.getElementById("")
  // elem.insertBefore(mypara, mychild);
  // elem.appendChild(row);
  var element = document.getElementById("tbody");           // afficher le tableau
  element.appendChild(row);                                 // afficher le tableau
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(cell1).toggleClass("bs-checkbox");
  });




// hidden une column

//   $(document).on("click", "[data-column]", function () {
//     alert("coucou");
//     var button = $(this),
//         header = $(button.data("column")),
//         table = header.closest("table"),
//         index = header.index() + 1,
//         selector = "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")",
//         column = table.find(selector).add(header);

//     column.toggleClass("hidden");
//   });
```

I want to disable the "ID" column with a button to either show or not show the column. So I would try some jQuery but I'm not really familiar with jQuery. So I'm asking, how can I disable with a button my column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript. All you have to change is the number 2 to the index of the column of id in your table.

Basically once the button is press we are going to loop through every row in the table and find the id column then toggle it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ToggleIdCol").click(function(){
    $("#myTable").find("tr").each(function(key, value){
      $(value).find("td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2)").toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
    <th>CC</th>
    <th>IDC</th>
    <th>BC</th>
    <th>CCC</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>vv</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="ToggleIdCol">Toogle Show/Hide Id</button>
```

Comment: thanks that actually working, but, that dont disabled my first identidication "1", how can i disabled everything on the column ?